# Вывод ячейки из таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

у меня есть таблица users c 3мя столбцами login, password, email;

я ввожу имя и пароль,нужно чтоб вывел email;

```
$st = "SELECT 'email' FROM `users`  WHERE `login`='$login' ";
$rs = mysql_query($st);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT 'email' FROM `users`  WHERE `login`='$login' ");
$array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo "Email: ".$array[0];
```

**P.S.** Хорошие мальчики говорят "спасибо" и "пожалуйста".

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 3):

Продолжаем

```
$st = "SELECT 'email' FROM `users`  WHERE `login`='$login' ";
$rs = mysql_query($st);

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $rs)) { 
print $info['email']; 
}
```